# AWK Preserve Header in Output

Tags: unix, awk

Hi I have a csv file like so:

```
order,account,product
23023,Best Buy,productA
20342,Best Buy,productB
20392,Wal-Mart,productC
```

I am using this solution from a previous thread:

```
awk -F ',' '{ print > ("split-" $2 ".csv") }' dataset1.csv
```

However the output produces 2 files without headers:

File1

```
23023,Best Buy,productA
20342,Best Buy,productB
```

File2

```
20392,Wal-Mart,productC
```

How can I modify the awk solution above to preserve the header line in each split file so that the output resembles:

File 1

```
order,account,product
23023,Best Buy,productA
20342,Best Buy,productB
```

File2

```
order,account,product
20392,Wal-Mart,productC
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would write this:

```
awk -F, '
    NR == 1 { header = $0; next}
    !($2 in files) {
        files[$2] = "split-" $2 ".csv"
        print header > files[$2]
    }
    { print > files[$2] }
' dataset1.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk script:

**script.awk**

```
NR == 1 { header = $0; next}
        { fname = "split-" $2 ".csv"
        if( !( $2 in mem ) ) {
            print header > fname
            mem[ $2 ] = 1
        }
        print > fname 
        }
```

You use it like this: `awk -F, -f script.awk dataset1.csv`

**Explanation**

- the `header` is stored while reading the first data line of the data file in the first line of the script
- for the other data lines, the script writes the `header` into `fname`, but only on the first write to `fname`
- this is achieved by storing `$2` in `mem`

Comment: doesn't work for me, I get a header for each line in the Best Buy file. Where is the `not()` function defined? Or did you just want `if (!($2 in mem))` ?

Comment: `mem[ $2 ] = 1` is not necessary, `mem[$2]` is enough without the assignment, since you're checking for key in array, not the array value.

Comment: Thank you, this worked too and the explanation was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

another similar `awk`

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 {h=$0; next} 
               {file="split-" $2 ".csv";  
                print (a[file]++?"":h ORS) $0 > file}' input
```

`a[file]++` is the line counter indexed by output filename, insert the header appended with `ORS` only before the first line, which will become the header for each split file.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this also worked very well!